# How can I pass a keystore in an application

Tags: sockets, ssl, certificate, keystore

I am currently working with SSLSockets and I want to create an application that will be released to the public - for example an android app, iOS app or similar.

I have a domain which is secured by an SSL-certificate. Is it safe to generate a keystore from that certificate and insert it into the project-jar and pass it to the user? Is the keystore still valid when the ssl-certificate has to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got the point, if you create a trust store with the leaf certificate (the certificate used by the server) in it you have to update it every time the certificate is updated on the server (depending on the used CA every 3-12 months).

Therefore the common solution is to include the intermediate or root CA certificate as those certificates typically have validity time of up to 10 years or more. If you include intermediate or root CA certificate you don't have to update the app if just the server certificate is renewed by the same CA.

Comment: Now maybe a quite generic question, but how can I get the intermediate certificate? I am on IONOS.

Comment: Any web browser connected to the https server can display and export the server certificate and the certificate chain including intermediate and root CA certificates. Alternatively you can use `openssl s_client -showcerts ...` to get the certs in PEM format.

Comment: @F_Schmidt: There is almost never a reason to include the intermediate certificate. Including the root is sufficient unless you have unusual needs. You may want to include more than a single root certificate from a single CAs to give yourself the flexibility to change CA. On the other hand, the fewer CAs you explicitly trust the less vulnerable you are.